# Restrict retrieved terms by category?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, terms

Is there a way to add a layer to the terms to be able to only retrieve the terms based on a category?

I have terms attached to multiple different categories, but a lot less in individual categories.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'vehicles', array(
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'child_of'      => $term_id,
    'hide_empty'    => $hide_empty
));
```

Is there a way to also add in the category? Example "Accessories" to filter yet again?

EDIT:

Illustrating my needs a bit more:

[image]

So i need to get the Vehicle taxonomies, there's a vehicles attached to ALL the categories shown, however I want to get all the taxonomies (vehicles) only inside the accessories, and if i choose a vehicle Make, i need to receive the children of that vehicle make taxonomy but still filtered by the category id (Accessories, 14901)

Does this make more sense?

Comment: Your code is already retrieving `tyre` terms that are children of only a specific term - `$term_id` (i.e. associated/assigned to that term). What else are you expecting? But for direct children, you could use the `parent` parameter.

Comment: In this case, the `term_id` is a hierarchal taxonomy, and I'm getting the children of a picked taxonomy item, so I could specific the "accessories" category id as the parent? @SallyCJ

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. What I meant is, if in the same taxonomy, you have a term named `Foo` with two direct child terms `Bar` and `Baz`, then you can use `get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'your_tax', 'parent' => 123 ) )` where `123` is the ID of the parent term (`Foo` in the example). But if the `Bar` term has a child term `Boo`, and you want to also include that, then you'd use `child_of` in place of the `parent`.

Comment: And actually, the taxonomy should be included as part of the *first* parameter for the `get_terms` function.. :) See [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/#parameters).

Comment: @SallyCJ - firstly, thankyou for taking the time to help, but maybe I'm not making myself clear, I've updated the post to help illustrate what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: So the categories are the default `category` taxonomy used for the default `post` post type? How about the Vehicle Make and Model? Are they custom taxonomies or terms under the Vehicles taxonomy? How are the Vehicles related to the Categories? Via a custom field?

Comment: The categories are woo commerce categories, yes sorry, vehicles is a single heirarchial taxonomy, and it has make as the top level, model as the second level etc, vehicles aren't related at all, that's i guess my issue, categories are linked to products, vehicles are linked to products, but vehicles and categories don't have a direct link

Comment: In that case, then you should first link/relate the different taxonomies. Because apart from the standard `parent` field which only works for terms in the same taxonomy, I'm not aware of any other ways to easily relate terms from different taxonomies. Are you using ACF?

Comment: The other option would of course be to make the Vehicles as child terms of the WC (product) categories. That way, you could simply use the `child_of` or `parent` parameter when querying for the terms. :) But if this option is not possible (to you), then try to link the taxonomies (or the terms) using a custom field and later you could use the `meta_query` parameter when using `get_terms()` or similar functions. Remember though, meta queries can become very, very slow.